# How to access all recipes of run_list in chef?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I was writing an HWRP and I need to access all the recipes that will be converged during the client-run. 
I was using **node.run_list.recipe_names** to access this. But it seems that it is **not** including recipes that are set via role.

```
For example, I have a node with run_list 
role[role1] that has cookbook1::recipe2
role[role2] that has cookbook2::recipe1
cookbook3::recipe1
cookbook4::default
```

If I use **node.run_list.recipe_names** it returns me

```
cookbook3::recipe1
cookbook4::default
```

**node.run_list._to_s** returns

```
"role[role1], 
role[role2],
recipe[cookbook3::recipe1], 
recipe[cookbook4::default].
```

Roles are not expanded.
How can I create a variable that has just the **recipes that are going to be converged?**
like

```
"recipe[cookbook1:recipe2],
recipe[cookbook2:recipe1],
recipe[cookbook3::recipe1],
recipe[cookbook4::default]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is `node['recipes']`. But remember that this isn't a perfect list, anything run via `include_recipe` only shows up there after the include happens.

Comment: Thanks @coderanger, However this losses the order of convergence. Is there is a way to preserve it?

Comment: It shouldn't, that's based on the run list expansion plus anything added via `include_recipe`.

Comment: My Bad, It is in order, but I don't want the include recipes. Just the list of recipes that are defined in the runlist. I am looking to access the variable expanded_run_list which is defined at lib/chef/client.rb (Chef::Client#expanded_run_list) or something exactly similar.

Comment: What are you trying to actually accomplish? This might be better asked on Slack.

Comment: Thanks @coderanger node["expanded_run_list"] did the job. I was working on this module [link]https://github.com/sidxz/inspec-handler  that does a set of inspec tests depending on your runlist. And so was looking for the best way to expand it. Thanks once again. I appreciate your help!.